# Disable TensorBoard logging on tf.Estimator methods

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

Is there a way disable the automatic TensorBoard logging when using the `tf.estimator.Estimator` class?

```
# Classifier
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=lambda features, labels, mode, params: model(features, labels, mode, params, word_embeddings),
    params=params,
    model_dir=str(MODEL_DIR),
    tensorboard=Fasle)  # <---- Something like that?

for _ in range(params['epochs']):
    classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(generator, example_generator._data['train'] ,batch_size=params['batch_size']))
    classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(generator, example_generator._data['validation'], batch_size=params['batch_size']))
```

I read through the [`tf.estimator.RunConfig`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating RunConfig for Estimator with `save_summary_steps=None` should fix this

Comment: Hmmm... tried with TF 1.12 and 1.15: no luck: tf.events are still generated.